# 23.10 Enable dark theme in file explorer pop-ups

Tags: themes, 23.10

I am using Ubuntu 23.10 and I have enabled the **dark theme**.
However, when I use "Open file" or "Open folder" in an app menu, the pop-up file explorer is in the **light theme**.
This is an example with VSCode but it is true for other apps that still follow the general dark theme enabled in Ubuntu :

[image: Light-themed file explorer in dark-themed VS Code]

It still works well for Text Editor, which follows the general Ubuntu theme selection even in the file explorer.

Do you know any way to ensure that any pop-up window will stick to a dark theme?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced a similar issue when I was using Ubuntu 22.10 and found a solution by **changing the theme to a dark variant** of the same.

Go to **App Menu**->**Tweaks**->**Appearance**. In this window, change the icons and legacy applications to a dark theme of your current or your favorite theme. In my case, it was "**Yaru**", so I changed it to "**Yaru-dark**". If you haven't installed Gnome-Tweaks in your Ubuntu, you can install using this: [How to Install and Use GNOME Tweak Tool on Ubuntu](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-and-use-gnome-tweak-tool-on-ubuntu/).

[image: gnome-tweaks]

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks a lot!